# Component can not be used as an entry component

Tags: angular

> Error: MyComponent can not be used as an EntryComponent

Above error message I get while `ng build`. The component is from another custom angular package's module.
What is most interesting is if I do ng serve and just save the my module again, the error goes away. But with the `ng build`, it stays.

Please also know that `MyComponent` also internally creates dynamic component based on input properties.

Comment: Did you add MyComponent to the array of 'declarations' in your module?

Answer (score 1):

I received this error after after forgetting to decorate my component class with `@Component{ ... })`.

Adding the component decorator fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding component to the entryComponents of a module

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had access to the custom library, and the error still persisted even after adding the component to `entryComponents` inside the library module. Turned out it was because of my `index.ts` file: Inside the folder of the library module I had an `index.ts` file which was re-exporting the module and its components. Inside `public_api.ts` of the library I used the export from the `index.ts`, so it looked something like this:

```
...
export * from './lib/shell';
```

Somehow Angular does not like `index.ts` files inside libraries, and I got the error (language service was also throwing errors, not recognizing the tags). Changing `index.ts` to `public-api.ts` fixed it:

```
...
export * from './lib/shell/public-api';
```